# Force port 80 address source on Python Requests module

Tags: python, python-requests

The problem I have is that I am in a server  in which I have no access to the firewall. I'm using `requests` module inside a `celery` task.

I need to get a set of images from another server. This server is listening on the `port 8080`. So, if I try to get the image by doing this:

```
requests.get('http://SERVERIP:8080/blabla/img.jpg', stream=True)
```

I get this error:

```
HTTPConnectionPool(host='SERVERIP', port=8080): Max retries exceeded with url:
/blabla/img.jpg (Caused by <class 'socket.error'>: [Errno 110] Connection timed out)
```

But if try to get an image from another source like:

```
requests.get('http://OTHERSERVERIP/blabla/img.jpg', stream=True)
```

Is not a problem of the server that has the image, because I've tried from other servers and it works. The problem (I am almost sure), is that the requests library is trying to get the image using the port from the url (8080) as the address source. If the port is not explicit in the remote host url requests use the port 80 for both the address source and the remote host, and everything works OK.

Any ideas on how can I force the library to use the por 80 on all cases (on the address source, meaning the outgoing connection, the port the server that made the request uses to listen )?

As Kroolik's comment says: The OP wants to bind a tcp socket to port 80 on localhost, and send http requests to the other server using that socket

**EDIT**

After all the comments I've read, I think I am maybe not understanding the problem. The most basic scenario is that if try to access any URL that is listening on a port different than 80 or 443 I get the error and I need to connect to a URL of an app that is listening on the port 8080. At this moment I've solved the problem changing some stuff on the other server, but I would really like to understand what the problema was here! Thanks!

Comment: By looking at `HTTPConnectionPool(host='SERVERIP', port=8080)` it seems that it uses the correct port and the server just doesn't respond to the connection... are you sure the server is up and running (try the same URL in your browser) ?

Comment: I have tryied with the browser and also from another server using requests. And if you look thar error line is using the port 8080, not the port 80 which is the one I want

Comment: Have you tried connecting to the server with CURL?

Comment: @limoragni `not the port 80 which is the one I want` then why are you setting the port 8080 in the URL if you actually want port 80 ? Either don't set any port (Requests will use the default port 80) or specify the port 80 with `:80` in the URL.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain myself. The port 8080 is the one the host that holds the image is using. So I have to connect to that port in order to get the image. If I use the port 80 it wouldn't return anything. The problem is with the outgoing port. It seems that requests choose the outgoing port based on the url. I want to stablish a connection from port 80 of my server to port 8080 of the other.

Comment: @r3mus Do you say is better to use CURL instead of requests?

Comment: No no, requests is fantastic. But if you can test with CURL, you'll be able to determine whether or not it's your python code at fault or the target server.

Comment: @r3mus I've tried with the browser, and with the same code from another host, the host with the image works great. The problem is with the firewall blocking my request on ports that are not 80 or 443

Comment: OK - so changing your python library to use port 80 isn't going to work; you'll need to change the server to *listen* on port 80. Correct?

Comment: @r3mus I don't have access to change the ports on any of the servers. I am trying to change the library so the source address is always using the port 80. But I can't find where I have to change it

Comment: If the server is listening on port 8080, it won't matter. In your code `requests.get('http://SERVERIP:8080/blabla/img.jpg', stream=True)` simply remove `:8080` and it will initiate the request on port 80, but if the server isn't listening on port 80, you will not receive a response.

Comment: The server is not listening in port 80, if I use 80 is going to responde with a 404. I need the source address to use the port 80 (the outgoing connection) without modifying the remote host address

Comment: The OP wants to bind a tcp socket to port 80 on localhost, and send http requests to the other server using that socket.

Comment: @kroolik get it right. Sorry if my english is not that good. Those are the correct words! And thanks for the OP part, but I'm just a programmer trying to understand some OP stuff! haha.

Comment: @limoragni: Are you sure? Web browsers don't send from port 80 to port 80. Can you confirm that your browser is successfully able to obtain this image?

Comment: @limoragni are you using a browser on the computer you are trying to use this code on or are you using a browser on your local computer? The former is the correct way to test this, the latter is not. Regardless, if you don't have the privileges to change the firewall then you likely do not have the privilege to bind to port 80. That is a port that the system reserves and which you will likely need administrator privileges to use.

Comment: @sigmavirus24  I've tried with a browser from my local computer. I'm using this server trough a ssh connection, so I can't use a browser from there, but i've tried with wget and is not working either. I can connect to any site and download every image or package as long as they are not on a different port than 80 or 443. By the way I do have administrator privileges on the server, but the firewall is not on the server itself. Any ideas on how to do this.

Comment: @Lukasa I think the browser wouldn't be able to get the image from that computer, being that I couldn't do it wget or CURL. But I'm connecting with ssh, so I can't use the web browser.

Comment: I sincerely doubt that binding to source address 80 would help you, but if you want to confirm it, try using [httplib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html#httplib.HTTPConnection), which allows you to set the source address.

Comment: @Lukasa I did, and it dind't work. Like I've said I'm far from expert when it comes to servers and networking. If you or any other could point me in the right direction of what could be the problem would be a great answer. Maybe I'm not understanding what the problem is, and knowing that would be good enough as an answer!

Comment: I think the problem is that your firewall is limiting you to connecting to _remote_ ports that aren't 80 or 443. You'll either need to get your server to listen on port 80, or put a proxy in between that can pass through your TCP traffic to a different port. If you're in charge of the server, the first is easier.